# Loop through each tooltips to add different TimeStamps

Tags: javascript, chart.js, tooltip

First item:
[image: First Chart]
Second item:
[image: Second chart]

As you can see what is circled in the chart, It wasn't supposed to be the same hour.
I'm trying to loop through my tooltips to print different dates to each of them, I tried looping but it doesn't seem to work, this what I tried:

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
    },
    //Problem probably here:
    afterTitle: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      if (data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index]) {
        return '<?php print_r($tempo[$mudarHorario][0]); $mudarHorario++;?>';
      }
    },
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
      if (label) {
        label += ': ';
      }
      label += (tooltipItem.yLabel);
      return label;
    }
  }
}
```

This is a part of my date gathering from database so you can have a look:

```
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $horario = (date('H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias']))));

    $tempo[] = explode(',', $horario);

    $geral = $geral.
    '"'.(date('d/m/y', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])))).
    '",';
  }
}

$labels = trim($geral, ",");
$mudarHorario = 0;
```

### Update:

I could get the data to appear correctly, I tried adding a loop so I can change the date but I don't know how to access each label to change the DateTime.
Here is a minimal version of the chart so you can try so, In this example the labels will not show because of the while loop, Link:  [Chart example](http://jsbin.com/veranuj/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: So what's the problem after your update? The display of the date in the tooltip and in the xAxis?

Comment: As you can see in the images, the date doesn't change at all, I tried adding a loop but It didn't work, if you could plz help me. I would appreciate

Comment: @HeadhunterKev For some reason, the loop doesn't run, It is like if the charts labels loaded and then when I try to loop the Hours to each label, it won't work.

Comment: Without code it's not possible for me to help you. If you post a minimal, reproducible example in JSBin or something similar I may can help you. Does it work with hard-coded values?

Comment: I get what you mean, but I don't know how I would be able to put all values manually, without getting it from my database. I will try to do a JSBin for you

Comment: Just ~three example values and dates, not more.

Comment: @HeadhunterKev, In this case, I added an array inside the js file just so you can use it, The chart is not opening the labels because of the loop that I added in the afterTitle, my intention is that each label will have different dates as the array tempo. Here is the JSBin : https://jsbin.com/veranuj/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I made [my own JSBin with my own code how I would make it.](https://jsbin.com/tuvawexaju/2/edit?js,output) It may not contain all your code and wishes. It doesn't have your exact date gathering, date format and I don't know what your `count` and `tempo` is supposed to do. Check my JSBin and tell me what I have to change and improve.

Comment: @HeadhunterKev It is exactly that. What you made was create an array with the dates and the time together right? But there is one thing, can you put the Date, for example: 11/10/19 into the labels? instead of nov 8, nov 10...

Comment: @HeadhunterKev oh, and will I be able to add info from the database too? From the PHP script?

Comment: @HeadhunterKev I just tried to made another JSBin file over the one you made, have a look at the callback/title part so you can see what I tried doing, link: https://jsbin.com/jamibexeki/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Just found how to do it, gonna paste the answer

Comment: OK, I'm glad you found a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

been looking into some documentations and asking for some help about array and came across this pretty easy solution:
Pass the PHP array to javascript array:

```
var date = <?php echo json_encode($yourVariabel) ?>
//In my case:
var date = <?php echo json_encode($tempo) ?>
```

This is how you can print values to each label:

```
tooltips: {
              enabled: true, //Add this true
              mode: 'single', //Add this single
              callbacks:{
//Dont need this title stuf if dont want to
                title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
                },
//This is the good part:
                afterTitle: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                  var date = <?php echo json_encode($tempo) ?>

                  return date[tooltipItem[0]['index']]; 
                },
//Dont need this title stuf if dont want to
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                      var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';                  
                      if (label) {
                          label += ': ';
                      }
                      label += (tooltipItem.yLabel)+"A";                  
                      return label;
                }
              }
            },
```